# Storing entity in Google Cloud Datastore with a custom namespace with .net api

Tags: .net, database, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I am currently developing a multi store ecommerce backend. Meaning that I have a backend service and one database for multiple webshops. For this I would like to use Google Cloud Datastore as my database.

I want to use namespaces to separate the specific store entities from each other. For example a product in namespace "1" is a product from the store with id = 1.

I am using the .net api to access and store data to the datastore database. How do I store entities in my database with a specific namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your Cloud Datastore connection, you can specify the namespace:

```
DatastoreDb db = DatastoreDb.Create(projectId, namespaceId);
```

Later on, you can create a new one by providing a new namespaceId while passing in the existing DatastoreClient:

```
DatastoreDb db2 = DatastoreDb.Create(projectId, namespaceId2, db.Client);
```

Comment: Simple. Thank you Dan!